# ¿Cómo implementar la función Validar Pila llena?

Tags: c

Debo implementar una función para validar si la pila esta llena, que envíe un mensaje por pantalla que diga "pila llena o pila no llena"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Para este ejemplo he definido una variable de tipo constante
#define Capacidad 10

En esta parte se encuentran declarados los prototipos de funciones

```
void insertar(int);
void eliminar();
void mostrar();
bool verifica_vacia(int tope);
bool verificar_llena(int Capacidad);

int pila[Capacidad], tope = -1;
bool vacia;
bool llena;
```

Este es el inicio de la aplicación principal

```
int main(){ 
int opcion=0, valor; 
system("title Estructuras de Datos -  Manejo de Pilas");
system("color 17");

do
{
printf("\n");
printf("*   Menu principal PILA   *\n");
printf("***************************\n");
printf("1 Verificar PILA vacia\n");
printf("2 Verificar PILA llena\n");
printf("3 Insertar elemento en PILA\n");    
printf("4 Eliminar elemento de PILA\n");
printf("5 Mostrar elementos de PILA\n");
printf("6 Terminar programa\n");
printf("***************************\n");
printf("\nEscoger una opcion (1-6): ");
scanf("%i",&opcion);

switch(opcion)
{
case 1:
vacia = verifica_vacia(tope);
if(vacia){
printf("\nLa PILA esta vacia\n");
}else{
printf("\nLa PILA no esta vacia\n");
}
system ("pause");
system("cls");
break;
```

El siguiente bloque de código es el que presenta problemas en la compilación

```
case 2: 
llena = verifica_llena(pila[Capacidad]);
if(llena){
printf("\nLa PILA esta llena\n");
}else{
printf("\nLa PILA no esta llena\n");
}
system ("pause");
system("cls");
break;
```

Esta sección funciona bien

```
case 3: 
printf("Introduzca el valor a insertar: ");
scanf("%d",&valor);
insertar(valor);
system ("pause");
system("cls");
break;
case 4:
eliminar();
system ("pause");
system("cls");
break;
case 5:
mostrar();
system ("pause");
system("cls");
break;
case 6:
printf("Programa terminado\n");
system ("pause");
system("cls");
break;
        
default:
printf("Opcion no valida\n");
            
}
} while (opcion != 6);
return 0;
}
```

Función que realiza la inserción de números enteros a la pila

```
void insertar(int valor){
if(tope == Capacidad-1)
printf("\nNo se puede insertar, la PILA esta llena\n");
else{
tope++;
pila[tope] = valor;
printf("\nElemento insertado\n");
}
}
```

Función que realiza la eliminación de números enteros a la pila

```
void eliminar(){
if(tope == -1)
printf("\nNo se puede eliminar, la PILA esta vacia\n");
else{
printf("\nBorrado elemento: %d\n", pila[tope]);
tope--;
}
}
```

Función que muestra los elementos en la pila

```
void mostrar(){
if(tope == -1)
printf("\nLa PILA esta vacia\n");
else{
int i;
printf("\nElementos en PILA:\n");
for(i=tope; i>=0; i--)
printf("%d\n",pila[i]);
}
}
```

Función que valida si la pila está vacía, funciona correctamente.

```
bool verifica_vacia(int tope){
bool valorDevuelto;
if (tope==-1)
valorDevuelto=true;
else
valorDevuelto=false;
return valorDevuelto;
}
```

Función que debería validar si la pila se encuentra llena, no encuentro la solución

```
bool verifica_llena(int Capacidad){
bool valorDevuelto;
if (tope==Capacidad-1)
valorDevuelto=true;
else
valorDevuelto=false;
return valorDevuelto;
}
```

Comment: Qué falla al usar esa función? QUé sale y qué debería salir? QUé error te muestra? Ve a [edit] y añade esa descripción de tu problema más allá de "no encuentro la solución".

Answer (score 0):

la solución es la siguiente:
se declara el prototipo como

```
void verifica_llena(int l);
```

luego la función queda como sigue:

```
void verifica_llena(int l){
if (tope==Capacidad-1)
printf("\nLa PILA esta llena\n");
else{
printf("\nLa PILA no esta llena\n");
}
```

}

y la invocación a la función queda así:

```
verifica_llena(Capacidad);
```

o:

```
verifica_llena(tope);
```

Se puede usar la variable tope o Capacidad de forma indistinta y el resultado es evaluable de forma correcta